# sp_whoisactive in SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2014, ssrs-2014

I have setup sp_whoisactive as a report in SS Reporting Services so people less familiar with SSMS can run it and see what is happening when needed. I have it working good and BUT I can't seem to figure out how to show the "sql text" column as a hyperlink in SSRS as it's shown in SSMS. Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks!

fyi, we ended up doing this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-a-hyperlink-to-a-url-report-builder-and-ssrs

**... add a hyperlink**

> On the Action tab, select Go to URL. An additional section appears in the dialog box for this option.
>
> In Select URL, type or select a URL or an expression that evaluates to a URL, or click the drop-down arrow and click the name of a field that contains a URL.
>
> For an item published to a report server configured for native mode, use a full or relative path. For example, http:///images/image1.jpg.
>
> For an item published to a report server configured in SharePoint integrated mode, use a fully qualified URL. For example, http:////Documents/images/image1.jpg.
>
> Click OK.

**After you add a hyperlink**

> (Optional) The text is not automatically formatted as a link. For text, it is helpful to change the color and effect of the text to indicate that the text is a link. For example, change the color to blue and the effect to underline in the Font section in the Home tab of the Ribbon.
>
> To test the link, click Run to preview the report, and then click the report item that you set this link on.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I couldn't get it working as I'm not sure what URL to put in there but we found another way where we put the "sql text" output on it's own row and have it hidden by default. If we want to see the query we can just hit the "+" button. I added a pic showing what we did, it works ok

Comment: Glad you got it working somehow :)  I'd probably suggest the URL be set to the value of the text that was coming back in the column.